# Facebook example JS login not loading

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-login

I'm trying to replace my PHP login for my canvas app with a JS one and have copied the Facebook example almost exactly from here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ and here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/.  However even though the alert prompt is opening the prompt for the user to accept the permissions isn't.  Can anyone see why from the code below?  I've been at this for hours now and I can't see how my code really differs from what was suggested.  Could it have something to do with the browser protection not running javascript?

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php'; // This contains app information
//include_once 'scripts/mysql_connect.php'; // This is the database connection configuration
require_once 'Database.php';
$fbconfig['appUrl'] = "https://localhost/FindAFlatmate-Dev/";

?>

    <html>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Profile Page</title>
    </head>
    <body> 
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '127865210690483', // App ID
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
        alert('Api loaded');

    FB.login(function(response) {
       if (response.authResponse) {
         console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
         FB.api('/me', function(response) {
           console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
         });
       } else {
         console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
       }
     });
      };

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document));

     </script>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However even though the alert prompt is opening the prompt for the user to accept the permissions isn't. Can anyone see why from the code below?

You are calling FB.login directly on page load, with no user interaction – so it’s most likely your browser’s popup blocker that is preventing the login dialog from showing at all.

The general recommendation for FB.login is to call it only on explicit user interaction, like the user clicking on a link/button that says “login” or something. This way the popup FB.login opens is less likely to be blocked, since the default configuration for popup blockers in current browsers is to block only popups that are opened “automatically” without the user requesting them in any way.